# With Noda Time, how to create a LocalDateTime using a LocalDate and LocalTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, nodatime

I have a LocalDate and a LocalTime and would like to simply create a LocalDateTime struct from them.
I thought of the following extension method which I believe would be the fastest but for an obscure reason the field localTime.TickOfMillisecond does not exist in the current version of the API. So it does not work.

```
    public static LocalDateTime At(this LocalDate localDate, LocalTime localTime) {
        return new LocalDateTime(localDate.Year, localDate.Month, localDate.Day, localTime.Hour, localTime.Minute, localTime.Second, localTime.Millisecond, localTime.TickOfMillisecond);
    }
```

So, am I stuck in the mean time to use:

```
    public static LocalDateTime At(this LocalDate localDate, LocalTime localTime) {
        return localDate.AtMidnight().PlusTicks(localTime.TickOfDay);
    }
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's much easier than the way you've got it at the moment - simply use the [`+` operator](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.0.x/docs/api/html/M_NodaTime_LocalDate_op_Addition.htm):

```
LocalDate date = ...;
LocalTime time = ...;
LocalDateTime dateTime = date + time;
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. For discoverability purposes, it could be worth including an equivalent method (especially as there are others for similar tasks).

Comment: @ErwinMayer: Indeed. I'll think about that... I'm not sure whether it needs to be symmetric though: `LocalDate.At(LocalTime)` and `LocalTime.On(LocalDate)`? `AtTime` and `OnDate` instead of just `At` and `On`? Will ponder.

Comment: I'd tend to favor LocalDate.At(LocalTime) if one of the symetric alternatives has to be chosen, as it follows the time hierarchy used elsewhere (year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds...). 
For code readability however LocalTime.On(LocalDate) also makes sense and could be nice to have in use cases where time is the primary information (vs. the date).

Comment: JSR-310 uses localDate.atTime(localTime)

Comment: @JodaStephen: Thanks for that. Do you have an equivalent for `LocalTime.onDate(LocalDate)`? I'm not sure it's necessary to be symmetric *everywhere*, but...

Comment: localTime.atDate(localDate). Its always atXxx(). See http://threeten.github.com/threetenbp/apidocs/

Comment: It seems the `+` operator is not defined like this for Joda Time. Is there an easy way to do this same thing using Joda Time? At the moment I'm using `localDateTime = new LocalDateTime().withFields(localDate).withFields(localTime);`

Comment: @FGreg: Use `LocalDate.toLocalDateTime(LocalTime)`.

Comment: LocalDateDate.FromLocalDateAndLocalTime(LocalDate, LocalTime) would be another one option. Also similar to whole other breed of FromXyz() methods.

Answer (score 4):

There is method available to combine LocalDate and LocalTime to form LocalDateTime

```
LocalDate date = ...;
LocalTime time = ...;
LocalDateTime dateTime=date.atTime(time);
```

Comment: Where do you see such method? It seems you are using java instead of .NET.

Comment: Yes In Java 8 this method is available not sure about the other version

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure why it's not in the API.  Maybe Jon Skeet can answer that.

I don't see anything wrong with the way you went about it in your second example, but you could calculate the `tickOfMillisecond` like this:

```
public static LocalDateTime At(this LocalDate localDate, LocalTime localTime)
{
    var tickOfMillisecond = localTime.TickOfSecond - localTime.Millisecond * 10000;
    return new LocalDateTime(localDate.Year, localDate.Month, localDate.Day, localTime.Hour, localTime.Minute, localTime.Second, localTime.Millisecond, tickOfMillisecond);
}
```

Personally, I think there should be a constructor for `LocalDateTime` so you can do this instead:

```
var ldt = new LocalDateTime(localDate, localTime);
```

One other thing - perhaps your extension method should validate the date and time are both in the same calendar system, and then pass that through to the result?  I've never used any calendar but ISO, so I'm not sure on that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you know if it TickOfMillisecond is missing on purpose or was it just somehow forgotten in the current release?
I don't see any Calendar property in LocalTime...

Comment: I really don't know.  Sorry.

Comment: @ErwinMayer: The whole TickOfMillisecond vs TickOfSecond difference is slightly annoying, to be honest. `TickOfSecond` is a more sensible value in general... but fortunately there's a better way to do what you want anyway, as per my ansewr :)